# How to organize bookmarks in the file browser?

Tags: interface, customization, file-browser

Is it possible to control the order of the bookmarks in the file browser, without resetting and re-adding them all?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current (2.76) version of Blender, you can simply hit the up/down arrows to the right of the bookmarks list. You can also rename the bookmarks by ctrl + clicking on the bookmark name (which is also how you edit file and folder names in the file browser)

Comment: Ctrl or double click them to rename. You ought to know not to put questions in answers ;)

Answer (score 4):

You must edit a file called `bookmarks.txt` with your favorite text editor (e.g. notepad).

This file appears on your configuration folder of blender, which varies in location depending on your OS. As bookmarks are user specific, it will be in the *user* configuration path for your operating system. See [the wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Introduction/Installing_Blender/DirectoryLayout).

## Windows:

For Windows it is usually in `%appdata%\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.69\config` where `2.69` is the version of blender which you are using, and `%appdata%` is the AppData directory of your user folder).

## Linux:

It will be in `~/.config/blender/2.69/config/`, where `~` is your home directory.

## OSX:

According to the [wiki page about file paths](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Introduction/Installing_Blender/DirectoryLayout), it should be in `/Users/{user}/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.69/config/`

## Portable:

If you create a directory called `config` inside the `2.69` directory (where `2.69` is your version) this file will appear there the next time you run blender and add a bookmark.

Comment: Thanks @CoDEmanX for the clearing edit. I'm taking StackExchange bit to bit.

Comment: You're welcome :) Isn't there a badge for like 1k edits? :D

Comment: You don't need to do this anymore, but it's still useful information.